# Как масштабировать текст в SVG по ширине

Tags: svg, scale

Есть бокс. Есть текст. Текст чуть-чуть широковат и касается линеек бокса. Текст нужно ужать до 95%, не меняя ни шрифта, ни его кегля. Каким образом это можно сделать?